# Vim command for switching window

Tags: vim, editor, vi, pycharm

I am using vim editor in pycharm. This editor is invoked using terminal which is available in pycharm. My problem is that, when i split vim window (:sp or :vsp), I am unable to switch to another window.(ctrl-w ctrl-w). It is obvious as most keyboard shortcuts, are not working in this integrated environment though commands are working fine. What is the command to switch window?

For more details:
I tried 'wincmd R'. It just switching position. But cursor remains in same position i.e. in old window. So its not useful. Is there any argument for 'wincmd' to actual move focus from one window to another?

Answer (score 7):

Did you read `:help window-move-cursor` and `:help :wincmd`?

The former has all the commands that allow you to move the cursor from one window to another and the latter is very clear about the relationship between `<C-w><char>` and `:wincmd <char>`.

If you already know `<C-w>w`, what do you think would be the right argument to `:wincmd`?